# Proof that image of a polynomial map is a cone

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Consider the nonlinear mapping $\phi: \mathbb R^{2 \times 2} \to \mathbb R^3$ given by $X \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} x_{11} x_{21} \\ x_{11} x_{22} + x_{21} x_{12} \\ x_{12}x_{22} \end{pmatrix}$.

I think that the image $\phi(\mathbb R^{2 \times 2})$ is a convex cone, i.e. in particular: for all $X', X''$ there exists $H$ so that $\phi(X') - \phi(X'') = \phi(H)$.

I do not see how I can prove this elegantly (!) though. I am looking forward for a general method that can be also applied for other cases. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A condition for $y = (y_1,y_2,y_3)$ to be in the image is that the discriminant of $t^2 y_3 - t y_2 + y_1$, namely $y_2^2 - 4 y_1 y_3$, is nonnegative.   This is **not** a convex constraint.  For example, $(1,0,1)$ is not in the image, but
$(1,2,1) = \phi\pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr}$ amd $(1,-2,1) = \phi(\pmatrix{-1 & 1\cr -1 & 1\cr}$ are.  Thus the image is not a convex cone.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Can you tell me a name for the theory behind this? Unfortunately I don't have a background in this. For example, is there a deeper role for the mapping $\phi$ and how do you know the condition that the discriminant of $t^2 y_3 - t y_2 + y_1$ be nonnegative? Thank you in advance.

Comment: We may assume $y_3 \ne 0$.  The point is that $t^2 y_3 - t y_2 + y_1 = (t x_{22} - x_{21})(t x_{12}-x_{11})$ has real roots, and therefore its discriminant is nonnegative.

Comment: Actually, in your example $\Phi(\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}) = (-1,-2-1)$ which would give the difference $(2,4,2)$ which satisfies the condition $y_2^2 - 4y_1 y_3 \ge 0$.

Comment: Check again.  For $\pmatrix{-1 & 1\cr -1 & 1\cr}$, $y_1 = x_{11} x_{21} =(-1)(-1) =  +1$ and $y_3 = x_{21} x_{22} = (+1)(+1) = +1$.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I got confused with my own notation from earlier. By the way, is it true that for all vectors satisfying the inequality $y_2^2 - 4y_1 y_3 \ge 0$, the difference of two vectors satisfy this inequality too?

Answer (score 1):

If we call $x_{11}=a$, $x_{21}=b$, $x_{22}=d$, and $x_{12}=c$, then we are actually computing the coefficients of $(a+cz)(b+dz)$. At this point we see that the image is exactly all quadratics with real roots. $b^2-4ac$ is convex, as the Laplacian is just $2$. The image is thus a cone.